# How to access javascript object without "name"

Tags: javascript, object, syntax

```
var text = '{ "employees" : [' +
'{ "id": 999, "username": "Batman" } ]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
var id = obj.employees[0].id;
```

Question is, how to access as in example above id, from javascript object?
In example above it has "name" to gain access to id, which is employees.
But real life example below i don't have "name" to use to gain id value.

```
var text = '{ "" : [' +
'{ "id": 999, "username": "Batman" } ]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
var id = obj.**WHAT TO PUT HERE TO ACCESS-->**.id;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can access for empty string as a key and remember that is a array inside, use the item 0

```
obj[''][0].id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this situation by using an array of objects (removing the external curly braces) like

```
var text = '[{ "id": 999, "username": "Batman" } ]';

objs = JSON.parse(text);
var id = objs[0].id;
console.log(id); // 999
```